# Edit Page option greyed out, page is not checked out to anyone

Tags: edit

In SharePoint 2007 I have a survey that I created and I need to add a web part to, but the Edit Page option is greyed out. I did some research and found this should be due to the page being checked out by someone else. However, this page is not checked out to anyone else. What else could be causing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Get you access permission level checked , It might not be a check out issue.
https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Permission-levels-and-permissions-49d456eb-d3c8-4402-86b1-deb911224afb

Maybe youhave only read permission to that page, Please check

Regards,

Giridharan. R

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer, it could be greyed out if there is no page to edit. Let me explain. I have erased all my site pages so instead of loading Inicio.aspx (my SharePoint is in spanish) was loading a blank default.aspx

Go to "site content" (literal translation from spanish- /_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx) and search for Recycle Bin button. Enter it and restore your deleted files